# Ubuntu 18.04 not loading

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04. On startup the display is black for 15 minutes, doesn’t boot and is stuck indefinitely displaying Ubuntu logo. Kindly let me know how do I boot successfully as I don’t want to lose my important files.

[image: Stuck indefinitely displaying Ubuntu logo]

Comment: Thank goodness you made a backup before attempting the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks SDsolar. The issue was 'unmet dependencies' which I resolved from root shell. And my files are safe.

Comment: I think for this reason this is happened.[A warning to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS users: you can't upgrade to 18.04 LTS through this guide because they already warned that it will not be available through 'do-release-upgrade' until 18.04.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ8T2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps below in order;

1) To connect to Wi-Fi from command line, I followed the instructions from this link ->
https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/connect-to-the-internet-from-the-command-line-on-linux/

2) Once the Wi-Fi connection was established, broken packages were fixed referring to the link below;

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/

3) Finally, the OS was upgraded according to this article →
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Please click the gray checkmark beside your answer to mark it as accepted which will change its color from gray to green.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting `nomodeset` in kernel parameters.

When grub loads and you get a screen to choose OS to load (if in dual-boot) or press `Shift` to load grub menu if you have only Ubuntu installed. Then with the Ubuntu option highlighted press `e`.

You will see something like this:

```
recordfall=1
save_env recordfall
set quiet=1
insmod ext2
set roothd(0,1)
search --no-floppy --fs-uuld --set 9009-9234
linux /boot,mlinuz-2.6.91.-9 root=i1U10=90.7bf99-923.1 ro quiet  splash
                                                                       ^
                                                                       |
initrd /boot/initrd.ing-2.6.91-9-generic
```

Add the `nomodeset` at the arrow indicated so the line looks like:

```
linux /boot,mlinuz-2.6.91.-9 root=i1U10=90.7bf99-923.1 ro quiet  splash nomodeset
```

Now press `F10` to boot.

If this works we set the nomodeset permanently as follows:

Do the above again, and...

Open a terminal app and type "sudo nano /etc/default/grub"
Enter your password if prompted.
Move the cursor to the line that looks like the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Add the nomodeset here so that the line looks:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Press `Ctrl-O` the `Enter` to save, Then `Ctrl-X` to exit.

In the terminal, type `sudo update-grub` and hit enter.
Once complete, you should be able to reboot your computer with this change made.

Comment: Many thanks for your response xypnox. The issue was 'unmet dependencies' which I resolved from root shell.

Comment: @SuhasGowda If you found a suitable way to tackle your problem you should post an answer so that people having the same problem can see what worked

Comment: It worked for me. I set up a virtual machine and had this error