# Pointer Randomly Jumps Ahead in Ubuntu 18.04 (Razer Blade 2017)

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, laptop, synaptics, cursor

So I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, and my mouse pointer has been acting weird. When I use an external mouse, the pointer works relatively smoothly, but when I use my synaptic touchpad built into my Razer Blade 2017, it is slightly laggy and jumps ahead, up to an inch, in the direction my pointer is moving to. When I restart my laptop, the jumpiness is minimised. However, when I suspend my computer and resume after a fresh restart, the jumpiness is increased. Furthermore, the more programs I run at once, the jumpier the pointer is. The pointer was never a problem in 16.04.

This is my xinput list output:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15
```

If I recall the xinput list from ubntu 16.04 correctly, an element with the words "synaptics" and "touchpad" should be displayed within the "Virtual core pointer" section. Also, the list doesn't change when my external mouse is connected.

When I try the synclient command, I get this:

```
$ synclient -l
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

In 16.04 this command worked and displayed the setting values.

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035863/848266):

```
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

However, it didn't fix anything.

I also tried [this command suggested by a person with the exact same laptop and LTS version as me](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030480):

```
$ sudo apt install libinput-tools
```

There was no noticeable improvements. 
I have also tried other methods, but they also didn't fix the problem.

It might be worth mentioning that when I was upgrading to 18.04, it failed/crashed mid installation. I used [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033551/848266) to finish upgrading to 18.04.